# Send UDP Broadcast on RasPi 3

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I need to send a UDP broadcast from a RaspberryPi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core. My code so far:

```
internal class UdpInterface : IDisposable
{
    private UdpClient udpClient;

    internal UdpInterface(int localPort)
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient(localPort);
        udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    }

    internal void BroadcastMessage(string message, int targetPort)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, targetPort);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ip);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        udpClient.Close();
        udpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I call it like this from a GPIO pin `ValueChanged` event:

```
_udp.BroadcastMessage("Video" + PinMapper(sender.PinNumber), _port);
```

I tried setting the `Internet (Client & Server)` capability in `package.appxmanifest`, and I tried using the `DatagramSocket` class before.

Do I need some other permissions/capabilities or is something wrong with my code? It did work when sending to target IPs before.

I'm verifying the packet with PacketSender on my dev machine.

Comment: where do you call `BroadcastMessage`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I edited it into the question

Comment: That code works for me on a regular PC. How many network interfaces has your windows? Try disabling all except one and try again.

Comment: @lilo0 still don't recieve anything.. I guess it's a network thing then, I have a weird connection between the RasPi and my machine. I'll see if a crossover connection or maybe with a switch inbetween will work.

Comment: I think It's better to go step by step. First: try to check that Raspberry is the problem, Install something like wireshark into it to check that no packets actually lefting it. Second: try to use network broadcast address instead of 255.255.255.255. For example, if your two computers are in 192.168.0.0/24 network, then use 192.168.0.255 address.